# nvme fw-download /dev/nvme0 --fw=S5Z42109.bin RETURNS NVMe status: INVALID_FIELD: A reserved coded value or an unsupported value field(0x2)

Tags: nvme

I purchased an Intel NUC11 with a Kingston UME A2000 2TB! Installed Ubuntu, hostname UNANUC11. Having lots of fun.
Concerned about possible problems with the firmware so I'm trying to Update it.

Using these steps:  I get the error NVMe status: INVALID_FIELD: A reserved coded value or an unsupported value in a defined field(0x2)

A:  root@UNANUC11:/home/craig# nvme list  # I have a KINGSTON SNVS2000G

```
Node             SN                   Model                                   
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- 
/dev/nvme0n1     50026B738150A760     KINGSTON SNVS2000G 

Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
--------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
1           2.00  TB /   2.00  TB    512   B +  0 B   S8442105
```

B:  root@UNANUC11:/home/craig# nvme version  #nvme command version
nvme version 1.9

C:  https://www.kingston.com/en/support/technical/ksm-firmware-update  #Firmware Update Information

```
Firmware Rev. S5Z42109 (03-30-2021)
• Fixed an issue that might cause the drive to become unresponsive on Linux systems
• Fixed a compatibility issue with the Asus Armoury Crate tool
```

D:  https://github.com/vulgo/kingston-a2000-firmware-bin-linux/find/main # Download the software

```
root@UNANUC11:/home/craig/Downloads# ls -l S5Z42109.bin

-rw-rw-r-- 1 craig craig 1335296 Jul 14 06:22 S5Z42109.bin


root@UNANUC11:/home/craig/Downloads# md5sum S5Z42109.bin

ecfd95b1ea517f4fcd4fa412fb56c8be  S5Z42109.bin
```

1)Ensure linux distribution has latest nvme-cli installed

craig@UNANUC11:~$ nvme version
nvme version 1.9

2)Gain root access sudo -s

3)Copy the binary zip file attached into a local directory

3)Extract the zip file that contains the firmware binary.

4)Execute fw-download command to prestage the firmware for commit. Note: Use the "S5Z42109.bin" binary file

nvme fw-download /dev/nvme0 --fw=S5Z42109.bin

NVMe status: INVALID_FIELD: A reserved coded value or an unsupported value in a defined field(0x2)

I'm unable to find a solution for this.

My system is up to date.  Kernel 5.15.0-4